# How to change height of md-slider ticks?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am setting `tick-interval="1"` in md-slider and I want to set height of tick to create scale for slider.

How can I change this height?

I found out that when I add rule with 'ng-deep'

```
.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-ticks {
   height: 5px !important;
}
```

Last tick changes it's height and I don't know how to change height of others.

Answer (score 1):

Writing it down in SCSS, this is if you want the ticks to be `10px` high:

```
.mat-slider-horizontal{

  .mat-slider-wrapper {
    height: 10px !important;

    &:after {
      margin-top: -4px;
      height: 10px !important;
    }
  }

  .mat-slider-ticks-container {
    margin-top: -4px;
    height: 10px !important;
  }

  .mat-slider-ticks {
    height: 10px !important;
  }

  .mat-slider-thumb-container {
    margin-top: -4px;
  }
}
```